How to replace a random string in an HTML table?
I have an HTML file and I want to replace a string that is included between two HTML table tags. Here is an example of what I have:
<tr class="noBorder"><td>string1</td><td>string2</td><td>string3</td><td>string4</td><td>random string</td></tr>

I want to replace only random string with something else on only one specific line. In my table, the cell containing random string is the last cell.
I tried this:
sed -e '28s/\(<td>\).*\(<\/td><\/tr>\)/<td>!!variable instead of random!!<\/td><\/tr>/' file.html

but it replaced with the following (so I lost all the stuff before):
<tr class="noBorder"><td>!!variable instead of random!!</td></tr>

What I try to achieve is this
<tr class="noBorder"><td>string1</td><td>string2</td><td>string3</td><td>string4</td><td>!!variable instead of random!!</td></tr>

Thanks to all who can help me solve this.

Here is a funny read about parsing HTML with regex

And a less funny, but actually useful, correct and informative one. that demonstrates that while it is, strictly speaking, possible to do this with regexes, it is very hard and not a good idea.

Don't use regexes to parse HTML. Use an HTML parser.

If your HTML is not a strict subset of XML (i.e. e.g. it contains improperly formatted self-enclosing tags such as <br> etc): you could use Perl with the Mojolicious framework (sudo apt install libmojolicious-perl)
If your HTML is a strict subset of XML (i.e. e.g. it doesn't contain improperly formatted self-enclosing tags such as <br> etc): you could use xmlstarlet (sudo apt install xmlstarlet)

If unsure, go with the first method, as it's supposed to work on any input, and also has the advantage of not changing the document's formatting.
Given the following:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Table "foo" -->
    <table id="foo">
        <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

Using Perl with the Mojolicious framework, to replace the contents of the last cell of row 2 in the table foo, you would do:
perl -mMojo::DOM -0777e '
    my $d = Mojo::DOM -> new;
    $d ->
        parse(<>) ->
        find("table[id=\"foo\"] tr:nth-child(2) td:last-child") ->
        [0] ->
        content("Replacement");
    print $d -> to_string
' page.html


table[id=\"foo\"] tr:nth-child(2) td:last-child: finds the last td of the second tr of the first table with id foo (which you should only have one of by the way)

% perl -mMojo::DOM -0777e '
    my $d = Mojo::DOM -> new;
    $d ->
        parse(<>) ->
        find("table[id=\"foo\"] tr:nth-child(2) td:last-child") ->
        [0] ->
        content("Replacement");
    print $d -> to_string
' page.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Foo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Table "foo" -->
    <table id="foo">
        <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Replacement</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Col1</td><td>Col2</td><td>Col3</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

The Mojo::DOM class can parse HTML; its find() method will accept Mojo::DOM::CSS selectors (which pretty much mirror standard CSS selectors), as opposed to xmlstarlet's XPath paths.

As pointed out by Ferrybig in the comments, this method involving xmlstarlet works well only when the target HTML is a strict subset of XML, and will fail, e.g., on improperly formatted self-enclosing tags such as <br>.
But it's fine for simple cases such as the previous example in this answer.
Using xmlstarlet, to replace the contents of the last cell of row 2 in the table foo, you would do:
xmlstarlet ed -u '//table[@id="foo"]/tr[2]/td[last()]' -v 'Replacement' page.html | sed 1d


//table[@id="foo"]: addresses all tables with id foo (which you should only have one of by the way)
/tr[2]: addresses the second tr element
/td[last()]: addresses the last td element

The sed '1d' command unfortunately is needed because xmlstarlet will insert an XML version tag at the start. I haven't found a way to prevent that.
% xmlstarlet ed -u 'html/body/table[@id="foo"]/tr[2]/td[last()]' -v 'Replacement' page.html | sed 1d
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Table "foo" -->
    <table id="foo">
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td>Col3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td>Replacement</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Col1</td>
        <td>Col2</td>
        <td>Col3</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>



xmlstarlet is designed to work with XML, not HTML. Not every HTML is valid XML or the other way around. While it works for this example, you should really use an HTML parser, not an XML parser. (One think it fails with are the HTML img tag, which does not require a closing tag, but xmlstarlet demands it)

@Ferrybig Cheers, I've added another method using Mojolicious to cater for self enclosing tags (and basically any HTML that is not a subset of XML)

@kos You can also pass the original HTML to the hxclean command from the html-xml-utils package and then use xmlstarlet on the the output. (disclaimer: I haven't used it on very complicated HTML documents, but it worked on most of the tries I did)

@Dan I can't find a thorough description for it, what would it do? I read it "fixes broken html" using heuristics, what are you suggesting it would be useful for exactly?

@kos It will make HTML structure XML compatible so you can pipe the result to xmlstarlet. Please keep in mind, that my comment was more of a tip than a solution. Which is why I didn't post it as an answer. I don't know how it works on large complicated HTML docs (for example, multi-nested and all unclosed HTML tags).

@Dan I now see what you mean, it'd fix an improperly-formatted self-enclosing tag such as <br>. That's very useful to know thanks! Unfortunately. besides the fact that it will put arbitrary HTML tags such as <p></p> where mandated (which is fair game), kinda aggravatingly, it will completely disrupt formatting as well (whitespace was gone completely in my tests), much more than xmlstarlet, so it's a very useful trick to know in general, it's probably not an option if you need to work on the page manually later on. But thanks for pointing that out! One can certainly make use of it

Kos has given you the Right Way®, use that. It is safer, more robust, easier to maintain in the long run etc. I want to explain why your sed failed. You are replacing everything from the first <td>, you aren't trying to specify which <td> to affect. The expression .* will always try to find the longest match, so <td>.*</td> will match from the first <td> to the last </td>. You are also using a needlessly complex expression there. None of the \( are needed.
This sed command will do what you want assuming you have that exact string on line 28 of your file:
sed '28s/<td>[^<]*/<td>!!variable instead of random!!/5' file

The s operator can take a number at the end to indicate "substitute the Nth occurrence of this pattern". In this case, you want to replace the 5th <td> and all text after it until the first < with your replacement, so we match <td> and then 0 or more non-< characters ([^<]*), and replace that with <td> again and your replacement text. This looks like:
$ sed '28s|<td>[^<]*|<td>!!variable instead of random!!|5' file | awk NR==28
<tr class="noBorder"><td>string1</td><td>string2</td><td>string3</td><td>string4</td><td>!!variable instead of random!!</td></tr>

But seriously, don't do this. It will break at the slightest change in the input format, can't work if the table is properly formatted accross several lines etc. Just use a proper parser as suggested by Kos.

Thanks a lot everyone.  Kos have a good clue but I don't wanna change the HTML because it comes from another server.  The Perl method should be interesting but I'm not good with Perl..  The sed provided works like a charm and easy for me to used it in a one-liner in a .sh file called in my crontab.

@DenysLaflamme If there's something that it's not clear about the answer feel free to write a comment under my answer asking for clarifications; the Perl method only involves changing the CSS selector to fit your case (the "table[id=\"foo\"] tr:nth-child(2) td:last-child" part - make sure you escape double quotes as in the example) using a syntax that pretty much mirrors standard CSS selectors (if you know a bit of CSS, it should be very easy to use that method). I can help with writing a selector that fits your case exactly if you want to show your full HTML.

Regardless, if terdon's answer helped you please remember to accept his answer, to let others know that his answer helped you and at the same time to grant him some reputation as a token of appreciation
